# Populate second Droplist depending on values of first Droplist

Tags: asp.net-mvc

How can I change the selection of a second drop down list depending on the first selected dropdown value? For example in the code below if the listDepartments is "Sales" I only want the choice for listCatagory droplist to be Customers, and when selecting HR I only want the choice to be "Resumes"  Is this possible with the code below or do I need a new approach, and if so is there a good example somewhere?

Thanks,
EB

```
                        List<SelectListItem> listDepartments = new List<SelectListItem>();



                            listDepartments.Add(new SelectListItem
                        {
                            Text = "Sales",
                            Value = "Sales",

                        });
                            listDepartments.Add(new SelectListItem
                        {
                            Text = "HR",
                            Value = "HR"
                        });



                        List<SelectListItem> listCatagory = new List<SelectListItem>();
                            listCatagory.Add(new SelectListItem
                        {
                            Text = "Customers",
                            Value = "Customers",

                        });
                        listCatagory.Add(new SelectListItem
                        {
                            Text = "Resumes",
                            Value = "Resumes",
                        });
```

When selecting the department is does nothing. 
OK I added this to my controller:

```
                    public JsonResult GetCategory(int id)
                    {
                        var department = db.Documents.Where(t => t.ID == id).FirstOrDefault();

                        return Json(new SelectList(db.Catagories.Where(t => (t.Department == department.Department)), "Category", "Text"));
                    }
```

But I am not sure where it get the data for data: { id: $("#droplist_Departments_ID").val() }, from??

Do I need to change way the droplist is for the departments?

```
                listDepartments.Add(new SelectListItem
            {
                Text = "Customer Service",
                Value = "CustomerService",
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to use Javascript in order to make an Ajax request passing the previous droplist selected item to a method in the controller which will return a `SelectList`, something like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'GetCategory',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: { id: $("#droplist_Departments_ID").val() },
    success: function (mems) {
        // states contains the JSON formatted list
        // of states passed from the controller
        $.each(mems, function (i, member) {
            $("#droplist_Category_ID").append('<option value="' + member.Value + '">' + member.Text + '</option>');
        });
    },
    error: function (ex) {
        console.log('Failed to retrieve states. Exception: ' + ex);
    }
});
```

In the controller something like (adapt to your db schema, obviously):

```
public JsonResult GetCategory(int id)
{
    var department = db.Departments.Where(t => t.Id == id).FirstOrDefault();

    return Json(new SelectList(db.Categories.Where(t => (t.DepartmentId == department.Id)), "CategoryId", "Text"));
}
```